# How to tackle questions involving count?

Tags: combinatorics

What is the method to tackle problems like:

**Count the number of times 7 have to be written while writing counting from 7 to 777 ?** 
Or possibly .

**What is the position of 'kitten' in dictionary when words are made [even if not having a meaning] using the alphabets $e,i,k,n,t,t$ only?**

I usually go on counting after finding some pattern of repeat but that fails often due to long time in counting and leaving a few of the positions........

Please suggest a way that possibly does not fail.

Comment: Or just the way we can tackle these two problems in particular....

Comment: In case of real problems(not math exercises), you can use any programming or scripting language to write basic programs.

Comment: @gev I of course need them for my math exercises.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ be the number of $7$’s required to write the non-negative integers having at most $n$ digits. Imagine writing all $10^n$ $n$-digit numbers from $00\dots00$ through $99\dots99$ in a column. Pick any column, say column $k$; there will be a $7$ in column $k$ for every possible $(n-1)$-digit number, since you can start with any $(n-1)$-digit number and insert a $7$ in the proper place to form an $n$-digit number with a $7$ in column $k$. Thus, there must be $10^{n-1}$ sevens in column $k$. And there are $n$ columns, so $a_n=10^{n-1}n$. In particular, $a_3=300$, so it takes $300$ sevens to write all of the integers from $0$ through $999$. To answer the question, you need only see how many of these $300$ sevens are used to write numbers larger than $777$.

Since $a_2=20$, it takes $20$ sevens to write the numbers from $800$ through $899$: in terms of sevens that’s just like writing the numbers from $0$ through $99$. Similarly, it takes another $20$ sevens to write the numbers from $900$ through $999$. Now we need only count the sevens used to write the numbers from $778$ through $799$. $778$ and $779$ use $4$ sevens; $780$ through $789$ uses $11$, $10$ in the first digit and one in the last; and $790$ through $799$ uses another $11$. Thus, the numbers from $778$ through $999$ require a total of $20+20+4+11+11=66$ sevens, and the numbers from $0$ through $777$ therefore require $300-66=234$ sevens. None of these are used to write the numbers less than $7$, so the answer to the question is $234$.

---

Suppose that the first letter of a word is not **T**; then the remaining $5$ letters can be arranged in $\frac{5!}{2!}=60$ distinguishable ways. Thus, there are $2\cdot60=120$ words that start with **E** or **I**. Words that begin with **N** or **T** come after **KITTEN**, so we can ignore them: we need only count the words that begin with **K** and do not come after **KITTEN**. This includes all of the words that start with **KE**; there are $\frac{4!}{2!}=12$ of them. It also includes all of the words that begin with **KI** except **KITTNE**, since **T** is alphabetically the last available letter; there are $\frac{4!}{2!}-1=11$ of these. $120+12+11=143$, so **KITTEN** is the $143$-rd word.

Answer (score 1):

Counting **7**, count the number of times $7$ from $1$ to $100$ and then multiply by $7$. And add the number of $7$'s appear which appear between $700$ and $777$.

And for the second problem:

Alphabet which appears first among them is **E**.

**EKTTIN**

Keep **E** at the first place and try out permutations of other letters: $\dfrac{5!}{2!}$.(Divided by $2!$ because of the two **T**'s.)

next:

**IKTTEN**

The alphabet which appears after **E** is **I**. So the number of permutations in this also remains same: $\dfrac{5!}{2!}$

Now the next letter is **K**. 
Number of permutations you get keeping **KE** : $\dfrac{4!}{2!}$

I'm sure you got some idea.You can carry on. If I didn't mess up the calculations, answer for the second one $141$st.

Comment: So, there is no other way than counting???? Please explain the first part more clearly.

Comment: Counting number of $7$'s?. Count the number $7$'s in period of $100$ numbers (That's $0$ to $100$).Then multiply by $7$, you get number of $7$'s till $700$. Finally the last period(That's between $700$ and $777$). And yeah! Counting **cleverly** is the only way.